# image is not draggable using inside swiper V11

Tags: angular, swiper.js, ionic7

Im using Angular 16, Ionic 7 , and Swiper version 11.0.5. In the follwoing html code I have image inside swiper

```
<ion-content fullscreen>
   <swiper-container 
    #swiper
    [options]="slideOpts"
    (swiperinit)="onSlidesDidLoad()"
    (swipertap)="onSlideTap($event)"
    style="height: 100%; position: relative"
  >
    <swiper-slide>
      <div class="swiper-zoom-container" #zoomContainer>
        <img  [src]="imageSrc" #image/>
      </div>
    </swiper-slide>
  </swiper-container>
```

The issue is when I zoom in to image im not able to drag the photo and see the other parts of very same photo. It means I only have one image in zoom mode and need to move through all corners of that photo.
I also added draggable="true" to both swiper-container and swiper-slide but didn't work

Comment: Finally I found the answer based on demo in the swiper website

I added zoom= true , in the swiper container and solved the headache
<swiper-container 
    zoom="true"
    #swiper
    [options]="slideOpts"
    (swiperinit)="onSlidesDidLoad()"
    (swipertap)="onSlideTap($event)"
    style="height: 100%; position: relative"
  >
    <swiper-slide>
      <div class="swiper-zoom-container"  #zoomContainer>
        <img [src]="imageSrc" #image/>
      </div>
    </swiper-slide>
  </swiper-container>